# Echo variable via another variable in twig

Tags: twig

I have this variable in twig: `banner_image_58`

I can access 58 via `post.ID`

How can I call `banner_image_58` whilst using post.ID?

I've tried `{{ banner_image_ ~ post.ID }}` but that just prints 58.

Comment: `{{ attribute(_context, 'banner_image_'~post.ID) }}`

Comment: What is the variable `banner_image_58`? Is that a path?